# Possible to draw text along an oval with JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to draw names along an oval in HTML5 using javascript? The goal is to be able to add names along an arbitrary offset on the oval like the attached image.

[image: Drawing on an oval]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `svg`'s `textPath` element to achieve this.

```html
<svg width="300" height="150" viewBox="0 -15 200 130">
  <path d="M0,50 c0,-65 200,-65 200,0 c0,65 -200,65 -200,0" fill="#645432" />
  <path id="shape2" d="M0,50 c0,65 200,65 200,0 c0,-65 -200,-65 -200,0" fill="none" />
  <path id="shape" d="M12,50 c0,-52 180,-52 176,0 c0,52 -180,52 -176,0" fill="#987C54" stroke="#8BAC96" />
  <text><textPath startOffset="30" xlink:href="#shape">Jonathon</textPath></text>
  <text><textPath startOffset="150" xlink:href="#shape">Sierra</textPath></text>
  <text><textPath startOffset="40" xlink:href="#shape2">Naomie</textPath></text>
  <text><textPath startOffset="170" xlink:href="#shape2">Daniel</textPath></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: woah.... very cool, thank you

Comment: How did you create the path for this? Did you trace it in illustrator or something? I'm not familiar with authoring SVG paths.

Comment: @patrickkidd - That is a hand written code without any vector graphic tool. If you want to change the `path`, you'll first have to understand the [`textPath`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextPathElement) element and how it works. Then, you could go ahead and create a shape using a vector graphic tool.

Comment: @patrickkidd - If you want, you could learn the [`path`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) commands.

Comment: Again, wooaaah. I checked out those two elements and it makes sense. Now just to get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: Once I got moving I had a subtler problem with skew, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247975/having-trouble-de-skewing-svg-text-on-path/28251428?iemail=1&noredirect=1#28251428